# Can't use scalatra authentication with latest version 2.5.0

Tags: scalatra, scalatra-sbt

I am trying build a basic authentication demo project with Scalatra. I am not able to find the right dependency for "scalatra-auth". My scala version is 2.11.8. I am bound to use scalatra version 2.2.0 Are there any recent developments in "scalatra-auth" with latest scalatra release?